# Where to place temporary cvs bulkload file for mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a small mysql database and I want to use a cvs file to load the data. Currently the data is in /downloads and this is not accessible to mysql. I want to put it someplace where I do not need to modify the config file to use the data.

```
mysql> show variables like "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                 |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| secure_file_priv | /var/lib/mysql-files/ |
+------------------+-----------------------+
```

I think somewhere under `/var/lib/mysql-files`, but not sure where a good place would be.

Comment: What is cvs? I only know of `csv`, coma separated values.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/downloads/text.csv" INTO TABLE mytable;
```

(?)

Otherwise use `/var/lib/mysql-files/` or you could disable this setting (see the configuration file you use to start mysql). This will disable it ...

```
[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = ""
```